# Find the smallest value of a complex number's magnitude

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the smallest value of $|3 + 2i − z|$ when $|z| ≤ 1$.

This is a complex number equation with i being the imaginary number.

A complex number is a number that can be expressed in the form a + bi, where a and b are real numbers, and i represents the imaginary unit

Can someone please help me with this question? I know $z= a+bi$ so |3+2i-a-bi| but I'm kinda stuck from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Draw your complex numbers as vectors in the Argand plane. What direction should $z$ be in to minimize the absolute value of the difference?

Comment: Draw a picture.  That should help you see what's going on.

Comment: @sasaki085 Equating the absolute value to zero is incorrect. Zero is not the minimum in this case!

Comment: Nitpick.  Finding the smallest value of $|3+2i - z|$ is not finding "the smallest value of a complex number".  It is finding the smallest value of *the absolute value* of a complex number.  The absolute value of a complex number is *ALWAYS* a real number.  And you can *NEVER* find the smallest complex number with a given condition as complex numbers do not have (total) order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|z| \leq 1$ traces a circular disc of radius $1$ centered at the origin. $3 + 2i$ in the Argand plane is the point that is $3$ units away from the imaginary axis, and $2$ units away from the real axis (in the first quadrant). The following diagram should help!

[image]

Can you now figure out the shortest distance between $(3,2)$ and $z$, which is a point on the disc? This should give you the minimum of $|z-3-2i|$.